# Trouble splitting string with split(regex) Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a number of strings similar to `name: john, id: 20, dest: toledo, from: seattle, date_time: [2/8/12 15:48:01:837 MST]` into only these tokens:

```
john
20
toledo
seattle
[2/8/12 15:48:01:837 MST]
```

I'm doing this

```
String delims = "(name|id|dest|from|date_time)?[:,\\s]+";
String line = "name: john, id: 20, dest: toledo, from: seattle, date_time: [2/8/12 15:48:01:837 MST]";
String[] lineTokens = line.split(delims, 5);

for (String t : lineTokens)
{
    // for debugging
    System.out.println (t);
    // other processing I want to do
}
```

but every even element in lineTokens turns out to be either empty or just whitespace. Each odd element in lineTokens is what I want, i.e. lineTokens[0] is "", lineTokens[1] is "john", lineTokens[2] is "", lineTokens[3] is "20", etc. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your regex is not matching `, id:` as a whole, it is matching `,` as one and then `id:` as a 2nd match.  Between these two matches you have an empty string.  You need to modify it to match the whole thing.  Something like this:

```
String delims = "(, )?(name|id|dest|from|date_time)?[:\\s]+";
```

http://ideone.com/Qgs8y

Comment: This works. I'm curious as to why the 0th index of lineTokens is still empty though, and why you pass 6 in for split()'s second argument (seems like it's just because the 0th index is empty).

Comment: Oh, the answer to both of those is the same actually.  If your string starts with a delimiter you're going to get an empty string as your first match.  Need to ignore that match.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a little less complicated regex solution.

```
String str =  "name: john, id: 20, dest: toledo, from: seattle, date_time: [2/8/12 15:48:01:837 MST]";
String[] expr = str.split(", ");
for(String e : expr)
System.out.println(e.split(": ")[1]);
```

Output =

> john
>
> 20
>
> toledo
>
> seattle
>
> [2/8/12 15:48:01:837 MST]

Comment: Technically `", "` and `": "` are still regexes.

Comment: @isbadawi: nice catch but you know what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your code:

```
    String delims = "(name|id|dest|from|date_time)[:,\\s]+";
    String line = "name: john, id: 20, dest: toledo, from: seattle, date_time: [2/8/12 15:48:01:837 MST]";
    String[] lineTokens = line.split(delims);

    for (String t : lineTokens)
    {
        // for debugging
        System.out.println (t);
        // other processing I want to do
    }
```

also you should ignore the first element in lineTokens, since it's the capturing from the beginning of the line till "name:...."

Comment: have you tested this? I think the output from your code would be, like, `lineTokens[1] == "john, "` instead of `lineTokens[1] == "john"`